# ES6: import specific values with namespace

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-modules

There is a specific thing i want to do from time to time, that i cannot figure out:

suppose `module1.js` exports 3 values:

```
//module1.js

export const a = 'a';
export const b = 'b';
export const c = 'c';
```

And then, in `module2.js`, I want to import *two* of these, into an object (as a kind of namespace thing):

```
//module2.js

import { a, c } as constants from './module1'; //<-WRONG!
```

So what I end up doing is something like this:

```
//module2.js

import { a, c } from './module1';
const constants = { a, c };
```

This works, but now `a` and `c` exist both in `constants` and also directly in the module scope.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: They're not in the global namespace, they're in the *module scope* of `module2.js`.

Comment: What downside do you believe exists to make you not do `import * as constants from "./module1";`?

Comment: @Bergi fair enough :D I updated the question

Comment: @loganfsmyth i guess it's an attempt at being deliberate, and only import what I actually use. If nothing else, It communicates to the reader that I only need those particular values.

Comment: Fair enough. A lot of people assume it is somehow faster, so I mostly wanted to make sure that wasn't the case here.

Comment: I was surprised when i found out you couldn't actually do what you're asking. Are there any plans to add this to the spec? Surely down the line where the es6 syntax could possibly be client side instead of bundled with webpack then named imports as a namespace would be hugely beneficial?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), you can either set an alias on entire module contents such as `* as constants` or a single content such as `b as constants`. But you can't set an alias on specific contents. So one of the solutions would be using *.

```
import * as constants from './module1';
```

Another possible solution would be passing `{ a, c }` as default.

```
//module1.js

export const a = ...
export const b = ...
export const c = ...
export const d = ...
export default { a, b, c };

/module2.js
import contants from './someModule';
doStuff(constatns);
```

Lastly, If you don't want to pass these constants as default, you can create an object and pass that object.

```
//module1.js

export const a = ...
export const b = ...
export const c = ...
export const b = ...
export const myCustomConstants = { a, c };

//module2.js
import { myCustomConstants } from './someModule';
doStuff(myCustomConstants);
```

Comment: I had not considered the option of combining default export and named export. Good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like

```
import * as constants from './module1';
```

You could also remove some if you need to pass them down, something like lodash pick

```
const cleanConstants = _.pick(['a', 'c'], constants);
```