# Import ES6 style, like as * but for set of consts to avoid duplication

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Currently, I have code like:

```
import { actionA, actionB, actionC } from './someModule'
doStuff({actionA, actionB, actionC})
```

You can see, there is a duplication in listing the actions, and this is my concern, I want to avoid duplication when listing actions. So I would want something like this:

```
import { actionA, actionB, actionC } as actions from './someModule'
doStuff(actions)
```

// someModule.js looks like:

```
export const actionA = ...
export const actionB = ...
export const actionC = ...
export const actionD = ...
... and so on
```

I don't need them all because there could be much more to import which is not relevant to current job

Comment: how you exporting the module?

Comment: like: export const actionA = ... (updated description)

Comment: yeap, a duplicate - closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I explained the same topic in this [post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). Same as below.

As per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), you can either set an alias on entire module contents such as `* as constants` or a single content such as `b as constants`. But you can't set an alias on specific contents. So one of the solutions would be using *.

```
import * as constants from './module1';
```

Another possible solution would be passing `{ a, c }` as default.

```
//module1.js

export const a = ...
export const b = ...
export const c = ...
export const d = ...
export default { a, b, c };

/module2.js
import contants from './someModule';
doStuff(constatns);
```

Lastly, If you don't want to pass these constants as default, you can create an object and pass that object.

```
//module1.js

export const a = ...
export const b = ...
export const c = ...
export const b = ...
export const myCustomConstants = { a, c };

//module2.js
import { myCustomConstants } from './someModule';
doStuff(myCustomConstants);
```

Comment: thank you, this is a nice approach. Although my main concern is that I want to avoid duplication. By duplication, I mean listing the names of actions. So when I list 3 action names in main.js and same time list them all in someModule.js its a duplication

Comment: I understand. In this case, you can export all the actions and pick the desired actions using lodash pick method. If it helps I will update my answer.

Comment: You might want to delete this answer and rather put the combined effort in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48936971/1048572) on the duplicate target question.